# How can I draw a radar chart and bar graph in the subplot in Python?

Tags: python, bar-chart, subplot, figure, radar-chart

I have a problem about putting a radar chart and bar graph in the subplot in Python.

I defined 1 row and 2 columns to put each one into each slot.

I tried to handle with this process but I couldn't.

How can I do that?

Here is my radar function shown below.

```
def radar_chart(values=[]):

    labels=np.array(['Crew',
                     'Length',
                     'Wingspan',
                     'Height',
                     'WingArea'
                    ]
                   )
    
    
    angles=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, len(labels), endpoint=False)
    #print(angles)

    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
    #plt.suptitle(title, y=1.04)
    for v in values:
        stats=np.array(ww2aircraft_df[ww2aircraft_df["Name"]==v][labels])[0]
        #print(stats)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
        ax.plot(angles, stats, 'o-', linewidth=2, label = v)
        ax.fill(angles, stats, alpha=0.25)
        ax.set_thetagrids(angles * 180/np.pi, labels)

    ax.grid(True)
    #plt.legend(loc="upper right",bbox_to_anchor=(1.2,1.0))
    ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.10),
      fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=1, fontsize=13)
```

Here is my code snippets shown below.

```
f,a = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(24,10))

radar_chart(values=ww2aircraft_df_top_5["Name"])

graph_1 = sns.barplot(data = ww2aircraft_df_top_5, 
            x = "MaxSpeed", 
            y = "Name" , ax = a[1])
show_values_on_bars(graph_1, "h", 0.3)

plt.suptitle('Top 5 fastest of WW2 warplane by their features', 
             fontsize=20, 
             fontweight="semibold",
            )

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('images/image10.png', bbox_inches = "tight")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Possible solution is the following:**

The dataset can be found [HERE](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/iskk97/ww2-aircraft?resource=download)

```
# pip install matplotlib
# pip install pandas
# pip install seaborn
```

---

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import pi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import seaborn as sns

# read csv to dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('ww2aircraft.csv', sep=';')

# select top-5 rows by 'MaxSpeed' column
df_top5_maxspeed = df.nlargest(5, 'MaxSpeed').reset_index(drop=True)

# convert column values to float type
df_top5_maxspeed['Length'] = df_top5_maxspeed['Length'].astype('float64')
df_top5_maxspeed['Wingspan'] = df_top5_maxspeed['Wingspan'].astype('float64')

# limit dataframe to required columns
df_top5_maxspeed_data = df_top5_maxspeed[["Name","Crew","Length","Wingspan","Height","WingArea","MaxSpeed"]]

df_top5_maxspeed_data
```

[image]

---

```
def create_radar_chart(df):
    # limit data drame
    df = df.iloc[:, :-1]
    
    categories=list(df_top5_maxspeed_data)[1:-1]
    N = len(categories)

    angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]
    angles += angles[:1]

    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0], polar=True)

    ax.set_theta_offset(pi / 2)
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

    plt.xticks(angles[:-1], categories, size=10)

    ax.set_rlabel_position(0)
    plt.yticks([10,20,30,40], ["10","20","30","40"], color="grey", size=10)
    plt.ylim(0,40)
    
    for row in range(0, len(df.index)):
        
        values=df.loc[row].drop(['Name']).values.flatten().tolist()
        values+= values[:1]

        ax.plot(angles, values, 'o-', linewidth=2, label = df.loc[row]["Name"])
        ax.fill(angles, values, alpha=0.2)
    
    ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.10),
          fancybox=False, shadow=False, ncol=1, fontsize=10, frameon=False)
    
    
def create_bar_chart(df):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
    df = df[['Name','MaxSpeed']]
    df.plot.bar(x='Name', y='MaxSpeed', ax = ax, legend=False)
    plt.xlabel("")
```

---

```
# create plots area
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
gs = GridSpec(nrows=1, ncols=2, width_ratios=[1, 1], wspace=0.1)
fig.suptitle('Top 5 fastest of WW2 warplane by their features', fontsize=16)

# add charts
create_radar_chart(df_top5_maxspeed_data)
create_bar_chart(df_top5_maxspeed_data)

# adjust space between title and charts
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)
```

[image]